# Fourier transformation with audio input in python

Tags: python, neural-network, fft

I want to recognize voices using a neural network, to do that I need to first get a good input for the neural network but by just giving the sound recording as input I don't think it would work because it is based on frequency and time. So I found the Fourier transformation and now I'm trying to transform my audio file with Fourier and plot it.

My questions are:

How can I plot a Fourier transformation with audio input in python?
And if that is working, how can I input the Fourier transformation in the neural network (I thought perhaps give every neuron a y value with the neurons as the corresponding x value)

I tried something like (a combination of things I found on the internet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys

spf = wave.open('AAA.wav','r')

#Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')
fs = spf.getframerate()
fft_out = fft(signal)


Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal)/fs, num=len(signal))

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal Wave...')
plt.plot(Time,fft_out)
plt.show()
```

but considering my input in the mic was 'aaaaaa' it does not seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all, your question better fit in [Data Science Stack exchange site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).
Consider asking your question here the next time.*

For plotting Fourier Transform, you need the absolute value (modulus) of the fft. (Unless in the particular case the signal is even and real, where the fft is also even and real)

For your inputs, just try to give to the network the amplitude of the fft, for all frequencies or maybe the first frequencies, because in general amplitude decrease fast in fft (or frequencies you think are worth to give after seeing the plot).
Maybe it's not a good idea to use fft, but I let you try it. Maybe you could find someone who already tried to make classification with fft. If you have struggle or you're stuck, try to ask another question on the site I linked before.